# Negative numbers are not displayed with minus sign, instead it is displayed with paranthesis

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, number-formatting, decimalformat

Language: Java

Concept: Number format

Implementation : Internationalization

Problem: When I try to format the negative number in the currency instance for the "en_US" locale, the result is displayed in parenthesis.

Example:
Input : 1234567.89

Actual Output : ($1234567.89)

Expected output : $-1234567.89 or -$1234567.89 ,whichever is correct.

** Note: I understand this is an accounting style and that is why I was trying to override the standard style but the result was still the same **

Question:

1. Why default currency formatting was not applied  - "standard"
2. Need a fix without a pattern because the pattern will vary based on the locale.

Below is the code :

```
Locale currLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("en-US").setExtension(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION,"cf-standard").build();
DecimalFormat numFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currLocale);
System.out.println(numFormat.format(amount4));

Any help is appreciated.
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing some research, found out that it is dependent on the JDK version. Until JDK 8, Java retrieves the locales from the localProviderADapter since the default was JRE. The currency format supported was only accounting style till 8 which means parentheses will be the default and no other option. Later with the JDK Enhancement, the locale default provider was changed from JRE to CLDR, starting with JDK 9 and as a result standard style of the currency format was the default. Later from JDK 14 onwards, we have both the - accounting style which was made as default, and an option was provided to configure the standard style.

So if you are in JDK 8 and need an inbuilt library or configuration option to format the parenthesis to -ve sign, then you will need to upgrade to JDK 9 and above.
Thanks.